# Converting data types in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssis-data-types

I get an input CSV file that I have to upload to my oracle database.

Here is some sample data

```
ContractId, Date, HourEnding, ReconciledAmount
13860,"01-mar-2010",1,-.003
13860,"01-mar-2010",2,.923
13860,"01-mar-2010",3,2.542
```

I have to convert the incoming column to DB_TIMESTAMP (to match the structure in the destination table).

But when I use `Data Conversion` to convert, I get an error

`Data conversion failed while converting column "Date" (126) to column "Date" (496).  The conversion returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.`

What should I do to be able to properly convert this data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you could do in this situation is change the Text Qualifer in your Flat File connection to be a single double quote (").

This will cause SSIS to interperet

```
13860,"01-mar-2010",1,-.003
```

as

```
13860,01-mar-2010,1,-.003
```

This also has the added bonus of being able to catch any embedded commas in your data if they are also qualfied with quotes.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the quotation marks [**"**] in the file.
You should remove them from the file or add a `Derived Column` before the `Data Conversion` component to remove the **"** with the expression

REPLACE([TextDateColumn],"\"","")